# Reset Git Bash Terminal setting to Default

Tags: git-bash

I was using gitbash terminal. I right clicked at the terminal window and open settings for this and changed the column and rows settings by adding one 0 at the last. After this I closed the git bash window.
Now when I am starting the git bash window, my system got hanged and I need to get the system restart everytime.

Is there any way that I can reset this column and row settings.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration settings for Git bash Terminal are saved in the **.minttyrc** file

1. Lookout for the file in your installation directory or the user home directory.
2. Update the file using any text editor as below

> ```
> Columns=80
> Rows=24
> ```

Comment: Not able to locate this file. Even I have done search for this file in whole system and there is no file with this name

Comment: Can you please help me with the Git Bash version and Windows OS version that you're using

Comment: For me the **.minttyrc** file is located at C:\Users\<Username>\

Comment: I am using git bash 2.32 and windows version is 10

Comment: If the file is missing you can create one using any text editor. Save the file as **.minttyrc** at **C:\Users\<Username>\**. Ensure that the file extension is correct.